# How to suppress a member in implicit copy constructor/assignment operator?

Tags: c++, oop

I understand that the he implicit copy constructor/assignment operator does a member-wise copy of the source object.

Say my class has 1000 members. I want to suppress ONE of the member when doing assignment assignment(and the default value applies), the other 999 members still use the member-wise copy as the implicit assignment operator.

For example:

```
class Foo
{
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    std::string s3;
    ....
    std::string s1000;
};
```

Then we fill object f1 with some values:

```
Foo f1;
f1.s1 = "a";
f1.s2 = "b";
f1.s3 = "c";
...
```

Now we copy assign f1 (source) to f2 (target)

```
Foo f2 = f1;
```

How can I achieve the following result if I want to suppress "s2"?

```
assert(f2.s1 == "a");
assert(f2.s2 == "");        //default value 
assert(f2.s3 == "c");
```

I understand that provide a copy constructor/assignment operator will solve this problem.

```
class Foo
{
    Foo( const Foo& other)
    {
        s1 = other.s1;
        //s2 = other.s2;    //suppress s2
        s3 = other.s3;
        ...
        s1000 = other.s1000;
    };

    Foo& Foo::operator=( const Foo& other)
    {
        s1 = other.s1;
        //s2 = other.s2;    //suppress s2
        s3 = other.s3;
        ...
        s1000 = other.s1000;

        return *this;
    };

    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    std::string s3;
    ....
    std::string s1000;
};
```

However, I have 1000 members. I don't want to implement such big functions.

If I implement function like this:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo( const Foo& other)
    {
        *this = other;
        s2 = "";
    };

    Foo& Foo::operator=( const Foo& other)
    {
        *this = other;
        s2 = "";
        return *this;
    };
}
```

Obviously, that's endless recursive.

Here is the only choice for me at the moment, which is:

```
Foo f2 = f1;
f2.s2 = "";
```

However, suppose there are thousands of `Foo f2 = f1;` statements in my project. Finding them all to append one line after them is way too hard.

So, I want the minimum code change to customize the member-wise copy of an object. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too agree with [@gsamaras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46461531/817643) that you must remember the single responsibility principle. But unlike their answer, I think you can have your cake and eat it too.

Let's examine the responsibilities of your class. For one, it didn't care how all the data members were copied. That responsibility was delegated to the type that each member belonged to. We should maintain that, since this realization makes clear who should be responsible.

The data member in question, `s2` is a `std::string`. That type copies itself. But what if we wrap it?

```
template<typename T>
class suppress_copies {
  T _mem;
public:
  // Allow changing the held member
  operator T&() { return _mem; }
  T& get()      { return _mem; }

  suppress_copies() = default;
  // But stop automatic copies (potentially even  handles moves)
  suppress_copies(suppress_copies const&) {} // default initialize the member
  suppress_copies& operator=(suppress_copies o) { // Accept default initialized "other" 
    using std::swap;
    swap(_mem, o._mem);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

And that's pretty much it, this is the type that's responsible for suppressing the copy. Just designate the member with this wrapper:

```
suppress_copies<std::string> s2;
```

Comment: Great. Your answer and @Remy Lebeau's are pointing to the direction applicable in my project.  What I don't understand is the implementation of assignment operator, why use std::swap? isn't "return *this;" enough?

Comment: @milesma - `return *this;` is to bind with the reference of the functions return type. It has nothing to do with modifying the member. That's what swap is for. Otherwise your assignment won't do anything, let alone reset `_mem`.

Comment: Same basic concept as mine, but I like this implementation better.

Comment: @milesma - Mostly nothing special. Anywhere a `std::string` reference is expected and the implicit conversion is viable, is will occur. The `get` member is for other cases. The wrapper isn't fully fleshed out, I should say. You could add forwarding c'tor and assignment operators to get rid of some of the need for `get()`. [Here's how the code in the answer behaves](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd13f00b31b9311b)

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry I deleted the comment (because I want to edit it). Is "operator T&() { return _mem; }" Called function call operator? Could you give me an example to invoke this function?

Comment: @milesma - It's a user defined conversion operator. You can read about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). It's fairly good.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks a lot. Now I understood your code. However, I have another question: You said: "You could add forwarding c'tor and assignment operators to get rid of some of the need for get()", how to get rid of get() if I want to access the wrapped member without a "get()" function?

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard about the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)? You are violating it with using too many data members for your class. Big functions and big classes are a nest for bugs, misunderstanding, and unwanted side effects. Just imagine the person that will maintain your code in the future..

As a result do not expect to get away with this that easily (I mean just a search and replace on your project is not that hard).

> How to really cope with this problem?

*Refactor*!

Use composition with compact classes targetting only at what they have to really do.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't invoke the compiler's default copy behavior for a class while also implementing custom copy behavior in the same class. If you perform custom copy construction/assignment, you will have to manually copy the 999 members while suppressing the 1 member.

You can implement the copy constructor in terms of the assignment operator, or vice versa, to avoid duplicating the copying code.  For example:

```
class Foo {
    ...    
public:
    Foo(const Foo& other) :
        s1(other.s1), 
        //s2(other.s2), //suppress s2
        s3(other.s3),
        ...
        s1000(other.s1000)
    {
    }

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) {
        if (&other != this) {
            Foo(other).swap(*this);
        } 
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(Foo &other) {
        std::swap(s1, other.s1);
        std::swap(s2, other.s2);
        std::swap(s3, other.s3);
        ...
        std::swap(s1000, other.s1000);
    }

    ...
};
```

Yes, it is tedious work to setup (but then, so is having a class with 1000 data members to begin with. Consider refactoring the class into smaller pieces!). Once it is done, you don't have to worry about it anymore.

A simpler solution is to write a separate class just for `s2` and disable its ability to copy its data. For example:

```
class string_nocopy {
    std::string m_str;

public:
    string_nocopy(const std::string &s = std::string()) : m_str(s) {}

    string_nocopy(const string_nocopy &) : m_str() {}

    string_nocopy& operator=(const std::string &s) {
        m_str = s;
        return *this;
    }

    string_nocopy& operator=(const string_nocopy &other) {
        if (&other != this) m_str = "";
        return *this;
    }

    operator std::string() { return m_str; }

    ...
};
```

Then you don't need a custom copy constructor or copy assignment operator in `Foo`, the defaults will suffice:

```
class Foo {
    ...
    std::string s1;
    string_nocopy s2;
    std::string s3;
    ... 
    std::string s1000;
};
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. Why you don't use swap in the "string_nocopy" version? 2. Could you provide a template version?

Comment: @milesma 1) because there's no need for `swap()` in that version, and 2) StoryTeller's answer provides an adequate template

Answer (score 1):

The most idiomatic way would be to have the members that need special processing know how to do it themselves (as in, embedded in *their* copy constructor), so to keep the copy constructor/assignment operator of aggregates always to the default. That's the idea behind having `std::vector` have its own copy constructor instead of having aggregates deal manually with each array they own.

This can work as long as the required behavior is general enough to stand on its own, and does not depend much from the rest of the aggregate; this is probably not your case - which poses the extra problems that (1) having an "autoreset" string (which only makes sense in the context of your class) as a member of your public interface is probably a bad idea, and (2) that inheriting from STL containers is problematic (although in this case it would work, since nobody would destroy it polymorphically).

So, for the cases where delegating to the member itself doesn't work, the only way out of this kind of problems (keep the default copy constructor/assignment operator *but do some custom processing*) that I found unfortunately is through an auxiliary struct. Put all the "normal" members into a `FooAux` structure with default copy constructor and assignment operator. Then `Foo` will inherit from this and add just the members that require special treatment; the copy constructor and assignment operator will delegate most of the work to the base class, adding just the custom processing for the extra members.

Answer (score 0):

`0.` As it's been said by @gsamaras, you probably need to redisign you class.
But if for some reason currently this is not an option, well, there are some tricks possible.

1. If those members are all of the same type, then store them in a container (e.g. std::array) rather than in thousand members.
2. Otherwise, hide the members inside an inner private structure with default assignment. Then, in the outer class' operator=, first remember current value of the muted member, then assign the structure, then restore muted member to the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually easier than you might imagine.

Declare a new string type, derived from `std::string` which has specialised copy behaviour. Then simply use the default copy/move behaviour in your outer class.

```
struct copyless_string : std::string
{
        // delegte constructors to base class
        using std::string::string;

        // implement custom copy/assignment    
        copyless_string(copyless_string const& str)
        : std::string()
        {}

        copyless_string& operator=(copyless_string const& str)
        {
                clear();
                return *this;
        }

        // and default move behaviour    
        copyless_string(copyless_string && str) = default;

        copyless_string& operator=(copyless_string && str) = default;
};

struct my_class
{
        std::string s1, s2, s3, s4;
        copyless_string s5;  // <--- won't be copied
        std::string s6, s7, s8, s9, s10;
};
```

Comment: There are a number of questions on StackOverflow that explain why deriving from `std::string` is a bad thing, even if it is technically possible.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it's a bad thing if you are expecting polymorphic behaviour. In this case we're not, so it's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It's worth noting that exposing a `copyless_string` is a little dangerous if people start using `auto` to copy it around.

Comment: @MatteoItalia agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Defer the non-copy parts of the class to a base class and handle them separately.

Then use the rule of zero to avoid writing any general case copy behaviour at all.

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

struct CopylessFoo
{
    CopylessFoo() : s2() {}

    CopylessFoo(CopylessFoo const& other)
    : CopylessFoo()
    {}

    CopylessFoo& operator=(CopylessFoo const& other)
    {
        s2.clear();
        return *this;
    }

    CopylessFoo(CopylessFoo&& other) = default;
    CopylessFoo& operator=(CopylessFoo&& other) = default;

    std::string s2;
};

struct Foo : CopylessFoo
{
    // rule of zero - no copy/assignment necessary

    std::string s1;
    // s2 provided by base class
    std::string s3;
//    ....
    std::string s1000;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.s1 = "Hello";
    f.s2 = "world";

    Foo f2 = f;
    assert(f2.s1 == "Hello");
    assert(f2.s2 == "");
}
```